# Discrete Math: Truth Tables and Valid/Invalid Statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I do not quite understand this problem very well as I am constructing truth tables and trying to solve them.  Could someone help me explain how you solve this?

The question is as follows...

**Consider the statements:**

P: $\sqrt{26}$ is irrational  
 $Q: (27^{\frac13})$ is irrational 
  $R: \frac{-4}7$ is rational

**What are the following statements in words and indicate wether the statement is true or false?**

$(P$ and $Q) \implies $$(R)$

$(P$ and $Q)$ $\implies ($not $R)$

$(($not $P)$ and $Q)$ $\implies $$R$

$(P$ or $Q) \implies ($not $R)$

Comment: (P and Q) then R is True

(P and Q) => (not R) is True

((not P) and Q) => R is False

(P or Q) => (not R) is False

Comment: What can you say about $P$, $Q$, and $R$?  Which ones are true?

Comment: P and R are true, Q is false?

Comment: Correct!  So, what's the truth value of $P \wedge Q$?

Comment: So.... False, False, False, False?

Comment: If $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, then $(P\text{ and }Q)$ is false, so $(P\text{ and }Q)\implies R$ is false.

Comment: No, remember that $A \rightarrow B$ is false only when $A$ is true and $B$ is false.  I didn't see you first comment in its complete form (you submitted it early and it was still incomplete).  So, I didn't mean to suggest it was wrong.  I'll look at it now.

Comment: Ah, okay thank you!

Comment: OK. I looked at it and you got three out of four right.  Remember, if $A$ is false, then $A \rightarrow B$ is true.

Comment: True, True, True, False!

Comment: Yes. That's it!  Implications with false antecedents are counterintuitive at first.  This exercise is meant to familiarize who solves it with how they work.